# Error on non-existent line Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I don't know what to do, I have a 39 line Python script and it gives me an error on line 40! :( Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Mass Storage\pythonscripts\Internet\execute.py", line 2, in <module>
execfile("firstrunSoup.py")
File "firstrunSoup.py", line 40

                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Mass Storage\pythonscripts\Internet>
```

And here's my Python code:

```
###firstrunSoup.py###
FILE = open("startURL","r") #Grab from
stURL = FILE.read() #Read first line
FILE.close() #Close
file2save = "index.txt" #File to save URLs to

jscriptV = "not"
try:
    #Returns true/false for absolute
    def is_absolute(url):
        return bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).scheme)

    #Imports
    import urllib2,sys,time,re,urlparse
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    cpURL = urllib2.urlopen(stURL) #Human-readable to computer-usable
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cpURL) #Defines soup

    FILE = open(file2save,"a")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'): #Find all anchor tags
        outPut = ""
        checkVar = link.get('href') #Puts href into string
        if (checkVar is not None) and (checkVar != ""): #Checks if defined
            if len(checkVar) > 11: #Check if longer than 11 characters
                if checkVar[:11] != "javascript:": #Check if first 11 are "javascript:"
                    if checkVar[:7] != "mailto:": #Check if first 7 are "mailto:"
                        jscriptV = "not"
                    else: jscriptV = ""
                else: jscriptV = ""
            if checkVar != "#" and checkVar != "/":
                if jscriptV == "not":
                    if checkVar is not None: #Checks if defined
                        if is_absolute(checkVar): outPut = checkVar.split("#")[0]
                        else: outPut = urlparse.urljoin(stURL,checkVar).split("#")[0]
                    if outPut != "":
                        print outPut
                        FILE.write(outPut + "\r\n")
                        FILE.close()
execfile("nextrunsSoup.py")
```

If you can help me, please do. I've spent many hours on this so far, and when it's finally ready, I get this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you dont have a matching except for your try

Answer (score 2):

there should be a `except` block after `try` and before the line

```
execfile("nextrunsSoup.py")
```

Answer (score 1):

so the body of your file is wrapped in `try:`, and where's your `except:` or `finally:`?